# How to share a Mac OsX host folder to a Win Srvr 2008 virtualbox guest so that it can be mapped as a network drive (no Vbox shared folder)

Tags: macos, virtualbox, virtual-machine, windows-server-2008, nfs

I need to share a Mac OsX (El Capitan) host folder to a Windows Server 2008 virtualbox guest machine so that it can be mapped as a network drive.

**I can't use VirtualBox shared folder functionalities because its basic ACL gives weird behaviors on PHP file system function checks (such as is_readable).

On a Windows host I was able to share and mount the folder and to map it as a network drive correctly. I need to reproduce the same on a Mac Host. I tried NFS but I wasn't able to mount the NFS folder on the guest machine.

Do you know a reliable way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

OS X can share folders over SMB. Open System Preferences -> Sharing -> Options and enable SMB sharing.